# edgeR: Error in optimize(commonCondLogLikDerDelta, interval = c(1e-04, 100/(100 + : invalid 'tol' value

Tags: r, rna-seq

RNA seq of bacterial supernatants with four conditions (groups "1", "2", "3", "4"). All conditions are in quadruplicate (except condition 2, which is in triplicate). Error arises at **estimateCommonDisp** from the edgeR library in this pipeline.

```
annotation <- data.frame("GeneID" = cds$locus_tag, "chr" = cds$V1 , "start" = cds$V4 , "end" = cds$V5, "strand" = cds$V7)

bams <- dir(path = "./data/input/reads/bams", pattern = "*.BAM", full.names = T, recursive = F)
ann <- annotation
fc_SE <- featureCounts(files = bams, annot.ext = ann, isPairedEnd = T, nthreads = 20)
write.csv(fc_SE$counts, "./data/input/counts.csv", quote = F, row.names = T)
write.csv(fc_SE$stat, "./data/input/stats.csv", quote = F, row.names = T)

counts <- read.csv("./data/input/counts.csv", header = T)
rownames(counts) <- counts[ , 1]

x <- counts[ , 2:16]

group <- factor(c("3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2"))

y <- DGEList(counts = x, group = group)
design <- model.matrix(~0 + group, data = y$samples)
keep <- filterByExpr(y)
y <- y[keep, keep.lib.sizes = F]
y <- calcNormFactors(y)
y <- estimateCommonDisp(y, design)
```

results in:

**Error in optimize(commonCondLogLikDerDelta, interval = c(1e-04, 100/(100 +  :
invalid 'tol' value**

everything is good until the last line (y <- estimateCommonDisp(y, design)). I've found if I remove "design" from this (y <- estimateCommonDisp(y) it will run; however, I assume this screws up the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it helps.

```
  y <- estimateCommonDisp(y, group=design)
```